# addEventListener(submit) and toggle('visible') function

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, addeventlistener

I'm a beginner and I'm struggling with a javascript document.
I want to toggle from 'hidden' to 'visible' a block that thanks after submiting a form. But the thing is that my 'thanks block' only appear for a second then disappear.

I've tried it by changing the 'submit' evenement by 'click' and it's working but then the form is not validate. I don't know if know what I mean. Thanks a lot

Here is my JS code:

```
let merci = document.getElementById('merci');
let button = document.getElementById('frmContact');


button.addEventListener('submit', submit, false);

function submit(){
    merci.classList.toggle('visible'); 
}

merci.addEventListener('click', closeMerci, false);

function closeMerci(){
    merci.classList.toggle('visible');
};
```

Here is the css

```
#merci{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

#merci #cadreMerci{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 20px 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}

#merci.visible{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

and here is the HTML document :

```
                 <form id="frmContact">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="fName">Prénom</label>
                            <input name="fName" id="fName" required autofocus />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="lName">Nom</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" required />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="email">Votre e-mail</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="message">Votre message</label>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button id="buttonSubmit" type="submit">Envoyer</button>
                </form>
```

Comment: You're not stopping the submit button from doing its job. And because there's no `action` attribute the "submit" acts like a "reload"

Comment: oh ok, thanks I've added the action attribute and now it's the same but it's just redirecting to my index.html. 
But my bloc still just pop for a second and disappear.

I've tried adding a .preventDefault() and it does work but my form is not sended then

Comment: If you need both then use AJAX, or show the "pop-up" on the site where you send the data to

Comment: Oh yeah thanks a lot! I'm using AJAX and it is working perfectly!